# Is it a structural issue if framing overhangs the slab by 1 3/8"?

Tags: framing, foundation, structural

I am having an addition built on my home. The framing is starting to go up and I noticed that one of the corners overhangs the slab by about 1 3/8 inches. I asked my contractor about it and he said it isn't a structural issue and that the foundation was poured slightly out of square. The corner is 1 3/8 overhang, but the overhang reduces as you go further along the wall, about 2 feet in it is less than 1/2 inch of overhang. The bottom plates are 2x6, so it appears like there is still good contact with the foundation.

It is winter right now, and the access to this part of the project wasn't the easiest. My contractor says this is somewhat common and that the pour had some challenges to it. Is this something I should be more worried about?

For more context, this is a single story structure being built. About 2 ft from the corner of this wall is an 18 ft wide 10 ft tall bifolding door, with a 10 inch transom, then another 3ft height of windows. There is a steel beam being placed above all of that to support the structure.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Assuming the 2nd pic is a wide angle showing where the first pic is, how far apart in time were these taken? The 1st pic shows quite a bit of snow on the ground, while the 2nd shows none at all.

Comment: The picture with the snow is two days after the picture without the snow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I may use this logic.

Walls for the longest time were only made of 2X4s. 3 1/2, maybe 4" of bearing at most on the slab. Since the insulation needs to much thicker these days, the walls needed to be thicker to accommodate.

Since you have at least the equivalent of a 2X4 sitting on the slab, you should not have an issue. Also, according to the second picture, there is a strong chance that is a non bearing wall, the two bearing walls are fully onto the concrete. The one wall in question only needs to carry the dead load of the wall, not the snow load if applicable on the roof. like the bearing walls do.